# JSF ajax not always fired, page reload instead

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a dataTable and a filter with a few inputs. In filter I have a commandButton with ajax. The ajax fires a method from bean which searches a database for the records which matches the criteria from filter and renders dataTable. The problem is that the ajax call doesnt't work always. I know it's strange, for me too but it's real. And by not always I mean that let say I make 5 requests (I click 5 times the commandLink and ajax works, data is changing, method from bean is firing) and than the 6th time it wont work, nothing happen (no request from client side, method from bean not called), I click once again and still nothing is happening and let say when click it 3rd time it works, but not by ajax, but by a normal submit and it reloads whole page. The numbers I gave are not always the same, sometimes the very first request I make doesn't work, and sometimes i works for many times without this error. 
Some code:

- table:

  ```
      <h:dataTable id="usersTable" value="#{adminUserBean.userList}"
          var="user" styleClass="table"
          columnClasses="col30, ,col140,col140,col200,col140">

          <h:column headerClass="col30">
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.selected}" id="check">
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup" />
              </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
          </h:column>

          <h:column>
              <h:commandLink styleClass="user-edit"
                  value="#{user.name} #{user.surname}">
                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true"
                      target="#{adminUserBean.edit}" />
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup check" />
              </h:commandLink>
          </h:column>

          <h:column headerClass="col140">
              <h:commandLink value="#{user.login}">
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup check" />
              </h:commandLink>
          </h:column>

          <h:column headerClass="col140">
              <h:commandLink value="#{user.permissions}">
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup check" />
              </h:commandLink>
          </h:column>

          <h:column headerClass="col200">
              <h:commandLink value="#{user.lastLogin}">
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup check" />
              </h:commandLink>
          </h:column>

          <h:column headerClass="col140">
              <h:commandLink
                  styleClass="icon-status #{!user.active ? 'blocked' : user.isLogged ? 'logged' : 'offline'}"
                  value="#{!user.active ? 'Nieaktywny' : user.isLogged ? 'Zalogowany' : 'Wylogowany'}">
                  <f:ajax listener="#{adminUserBean.selectUser(user)}"
                      render=":table:linkGroup check" />
              </h:commandLink>
          </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
  ```
- filter:

  ```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <h:form>
  <div class="filters">
      <h2>Filtruj wg</h2>
      <h:panelGroup id="filtr" styleClass="filters-group">

          <div class="div-table">
              <div class="div-cell">
                  <fieldset>
                      <legend>od</legend>
                      <a href="" class="icon icon-filter-off hidden" />
                      <h:inputText class="input-filtr date"
                          value="#{adminUserBean.userSearchProvider.dateFrom}" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
              <div class="div-cell">
                  <fieldset>
                      <legend>do</legend>
                      <a href="" class="icon icon-filter-off hidden" />
                      <h:inputText class="input-filtr date"
                          value="#{adminUserBean.userSearchProvider.dateTo}" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="div-table">
              <div class="div-cell">
                  <fieldset>
                      <legend>nazwa zawiera:</legend>
                      <a href="" class="icon icon-filter-off hidden"></a>
                      <h:inputText class="input-filtr"
                          value="#{adminUserBean.userSearchProvider.name}" />
                  </fieldset>
              </div>
          </div>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:commandButton value="Wyszukaj"
          styleClass="btn btn-blue-back btn-big wyszukaj">
          <f:ajax execute="filtr" listener="#{adminUserBean.search}"
              render=":table:usersTable" />
      </h:commandButton>
  </div>
  ```
- bean:

  ```
  package com.example.bean

  @ManagedBean
  @SessionScoped
  @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  @Controller
  public class AdminUserBean implements Serializable {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      offset = 0;
      sortCol = 0;
      sortOrder = "asc";
      cleanData();
      setUsers();
      reportSearchProvider = new ReportSearchProvider();
  }

  public void setUsers() {
      try {
          if (userList == null || userList.size() == 0) {
              userList = new ArrayList<User>();
          }
          userList.addAll(adminUserService.getUsers(userSearchProvider,
                  offset, sortCol, sortOrder));
      } catch (DAOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public void search() {
      if (userSearchProvider != null) {
          refreshUserList();
      }
  }

  private void refreshUserList() {
      offset = 0;
      userList.clear();
      setUsers();
  }
  ```

(I skipped some lines, variables decl. etc.)

I use pure JSF 2.2, Tomcat 8 as a server (I don't know if it matters).
I've read similar questions but I haven't find the same example as mine that the ajax sometimes works and sometimes not. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check browser's console for any JS errors or other clues?

Comment: Is it possible that bean method load too much data that it last to long for ajax request?

Comment: Why do you use duplicate annotations on the managed bean? Either of the pairs will simply be ignored as if it does not exist at all.

Comment: It's because I earlier use JSF only and than move to spring but I left annotations. I know it's wrong but it doesn't change anything if I left only one pair. Actually if I left only JSF annotations the bean is null.

Comment: I find out that sometimes when the ajax "hang", the next time I click it works, so the page reload isn't always present. The normal ajax request (when it works) last for about 300ms, can it be too much?

Comment: I made all ma beans classes, which are session scoped, implements Serializable and it seems to help a little bit. Now I have maybe 2-3 times this bugs for a about 30 tries But I still have sometimes NotSerializableExceptions on server startup but not in bean class but for instance in Dao or Service class. Does the Dao or Service should be Serializable as well as beans?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found a solution. I use a nicescroll plugin in project and when filter height is greater than height of window it becomes scrollable and you can scroll it not only by scroll bar or mousewheel but also by grabbing it by left mouse button and moving mouse up and down. It turned out that when I click on the button and make a little move on it nicescroll somehow blocks ajax execute. But when I click once again without doing any move (or when I submit by enter) the request executes but not by ajax, but normal request refreshing whole page. 
The solution is to simply remove nicescroll when mouse button is down on a button and add nicescroll when mouse button is up:

```
$('input.wyszukaj').mousedown( function() {
    $('.content-right-container').getNiceScroll().remove();
    $('.content-right-container').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
}).mouseup( function() {
    $('.content-right-container').niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: '#969696',
        cursorwidth: '4px',
        cursorborder: '0',
        cursorborderradius: '0',
        grabcursorenabled: false,
        touchbehavior: true,
        cursordragontouch: true
    });
});
```

And it works perfect. Ajax isn't "hanging" any more.